# IF Cell A1 = Yes then Fill Red Color in B1

Tags: excel-2007

I have a worksheet in Excel-2007

If Cell A1 has a value of 'Yes' in it then I want the Cell B1 to be filled in red color (irrespective of the content in Cell B1).

Comment: As I can see it you dont want a macro/vbasic-code to do it, you just want to conditionally format the cell. If thats the case I cant see that the question is programming related.

Answer (score 1):

[About conditional formats](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-conditional-formats-HP001173914.aspx).

Expand *Formulas as formatting criteria*, then expand *Example 3*.

[Example workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/conditionally-formatted-data-examples-and-guidelines-HA010230841.aspx) is available.

Answer (score 0):

Select B1, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule...

*Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
**Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=A1="YES"
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red, OK, OK.